# Android layout with error "Nested weights are bad for perfomance"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

im trying to do this layout above
[image]

and here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In ImageView, i got the error "Nested weights are bad for perfomance". I would to understand why this happening and if someone have a better solution for this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `layout_weight` attribute is another way of specifying a width or a height in percentage dimensions, and to optimize the calculation of the dimensions you should use `0dp` to one of them (the one you are replacing with).

Another optimize tip is to remove the `<RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>` that is not being used in your layout.

Please try the solution below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, still give me the warning

Comment: It is still warning you because you have `View`s using `layout_weight` inside a `View` which is also using `layout_weight`. Let us know specifically what you are trying to do and we could be preciser in our response.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Nested weights are bad for performance" happens because you have a weighted LInearLayout "nested" inside another weighted LinearLayout (see below). In order for Android to perform this it will have to draw the entire screen to get all of the non-nested layout measurements, then draw it all again to calculate the "nested" weighted layouts.

This can be a huge performance hit. However, I built one screen that had 4 layers of nesting and about 100 layouts, including lots of images. Rendering took about 5 milliseconds on newer devices, usually less. So this is really only an issue if you are frequently redrawing the nested layouts (like trying to animation with nested layouts). If you don't see a performance hit that you can measure in your logcat or observe while using your app, don't worry about it. Test thoroughly!

In other words, it's a warning, not an error.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <!-- THIS IS YOUR NESTED WEIGHTED LAYOUT -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does that mean? Do you need an alternate solution? The only other option is to write java to measure the screen size, which can be significantly faster

Answer (score -1):

I would rather write it as below. Notice using integers instead of fractions:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```